# Limitar en Oracle

Tags: oracle

nos han mandado un ejercicio en clase, y hay una cosa que no sé como hacerla. Os pongo el ejercicio y os explico

Vamos a crear las tablas para una Academia donde se imparten distintos cursos de informática. Empezaremos creando con *SQL* las siguientes tablas:

Tabla `ALUMNOS` recogerá información sobre el alumnado: Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2, NIF, Dirección, Sexo, Fecha de Nacimiento y Curso en el que se matricula.

Tabla `CURSOS` con los siguientes campos: Nombre del Curso, Código del Curso que lo identifica, NIF del Profesor, Máximo número de alumnos/as recomendado, Fecha de inicio, Fecha final, Número de horas totales del curso. **Los alumnos/as no pueden compaginar varios cursos a la vez.**.

¿Como haría para limitar a los alumnos para que no puedan compaginar varios cursos a la vez?

Es un ejercicio en Oracle, donde creamos tablas por comando en la sección de comandos SQL. Tanto la tabla de Alumnos como de cursos, las tengo hechas:

```
CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS (
 NIF VARCHAR(9) CONSTRAINT ALU_NIF_PK PRIMARY KEY,
 Nombre VARCHAR(50),
 Apellido1 VARCHAR(50),
 Apellido2 VARCHAR(50),
 Direccion VARCHAR(200),
 Sexo VARCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT ALU_SEX_CK CHECK (Sexo in ('M','H')),
 FechaNacimiento DATE,
 CodigoCurso VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ALU_COD_FK REFERENCES
CURSOS );

CREATE TABLE CURSOS (
 Codigo VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT CUR_COD_PK PRIMARY KEY,
 Nombre VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
 NIFProfesor VARCHAR(9),
 MaximoAlumnos NUMBER(2),
 FechaInicio DATE,
 FechaFin DATE,
 Horas NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT CK_CUR_FEC CHECK (FechaInicio < FechaFin) );
```

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes, los alumnos solo están en un único curso. Es una relación 1-1, si fuera varios cursos precisarías de una tabla relacional n-m

Comment: Una manera de lograr lo que necesitas sería creando una tercera tabla, que establezca la relación que hay entre cursos y alumnos. Podríamos llamarla **Matrícula**. Esta tabla podría tener como campos el NIF del alumno y el Código del curso en el que se matricula. Entendiendo que para que un alumno esté matriculado ha de aparecer en esta tabla, podrías definir como clave primaria el NIF del alumno, de tal manera que al no poder repetirse sería imposible que se matriculase en varios cursos a la vez.

Comment: @PHPMyguel Tal y como indica solo pueden estar en un curso, no necesita de esa tabla, ya que permitiría a un alumno estar en varios.

Comment: @osiris85 Es verdad. No me había fijado en que la tabla Alumnos tenía el Código del curso en el que está matriculado.

Comment: Mi duda es, haces unique el NIF, como sabes luego que ese alumno ha acabado el curso, pueda inscribirse a otro?

Comment: No podrías saberlo. En ese caso si que la mejor opción sería la tabla intermedia que menciono en mi comentario anterior. Al tener en cursos un campo FechaInicio y FechaFin, a la hora de inscribir un alumno a un curso habría que comprobar si este alumno se encuentra ya matriculado en algún curso (mirando la tabla intermedia matrícula) y si lo está, comprobar si la fecha actual está dentro del rango de fechas del curso o cursos en los que esté matriculado. Para hacerl ode esta manera tendrías que quitar de Alumno el campo CodigoCurso

Comment: Es que es eso, al no poder cursar varios a la vez, tiene que comprobar que ese curso se está cursando o no, y si ha finalizado, poder apuntarse a otro.